# NSSet setByAddingObject in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsset

What is equivalent of `setByAddingObject:` in Swift. I have an `NSSet` property from Objective-C in Swift. But since Apple released Xcode 6.3 I have an error in this place:

Example:

```
NSSet *set;

object.set = object.set.setByAddingObject("text/html")
```

It produces error:

```
'Set<NSObject>' does not have a member named 'setByAddingObject'
```

[image]

Any idea, how to fix this? `insert` method doesn't work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 1.2 added its own `Set` type, which is bridged over to Swift from Objective-C in a similar fashion to `NSArray`/`Array` and `NSString`/`String`.  Try `object.set.insert("text/html")`.

Comment: Assuming is: Use `object.set.insert("text/html")` instead of `object.set = object.set.insert("text/html")`